# How does root domain forwarding works in GoDaddy-Azure-SSL scenario?

Tags: azure, ssl, dns

I'm creating cloud service with custom DNS on Azure. As per [Configuring a custom domain name for a Windows Azure cloud service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/) article, I need to

> configure a **URL Redirect** or **URL Forward** entry in your DNS settings

fine, I went to GoDaddy's panel, clicked on `Forwarding` link and here is what I see:

[image]

301/302 implies to me that they use some kind of application server to do the forwarding. But how does it work with SSL? Won't THEIR server be rejected by my browser because domain name does not match to the certificate's one **before** it can do the redirect? If not - why?

Is there a "native" (i.e. at DNS level) solution to redirect naked domain to WWW subdomain? (i know CNAMEs do not work for root domains).

what if I need both http and https versions of my domain available - how should I set this up then?

---

I know that everything will be solved as soon as I add A-record, and IP addresses in Azure are said to be very "stable" as long as the deployment is not deleted - but wait, [Microsoft's own article](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/) says "A-record" is not a preferred way - and same says Heroku, S3, and so on. So I would like to know what my options are.

Comment: `301/302` refers to the standard HTTP codes for redirection.

Comment: i know - pls re-read my question related to the redirection codes then.